# Interpreting Gnu `df` command size results on Linux

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage, fdisk

I'm having a trouble understanding how `df` reports the size of filesystems:

```
$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used     Available   Use%   Mounted on
/dev/sda3      924815840     63819748 813948260   8%        /
--snip--
```

For the root partition here's how I interpret the results:

1K-blocks column this is the total size of the filesystem in 1K-block units. In other words, for /dev/sda3:

**Total size of the filesystem (in bytes)** =   1024 * 924815840

**Reserved blocks size (in 1K units)** = 924815840 - (63819748 + 813948260)

`<Used>` and `<Available>` columns only list the used blocks of regular users, excluding the reserved ones. Let's run `df -h` now to check results:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3       882G   61G  777G   8% /
```

I was puzzled by the `G`, `df` reports in `Gib` though, not sure why they choose `Gib` suffix instead of `Gib`. Same for the `1K`, it's really 1Kib. Now, I don't want to play smart here, who got the time for human intelligence these days! If you convert the units as I computed them above, you'll see that the values match, hence my interpretation of the size reported by `df` is right. The problem starts when you run `fdisk` which reports totally different filysystem sizes:

```
Device        Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda3  72265728 1953523711 1881257984 897.1G Linux filesystem
```

The size is substantially higher here (**897.1G**) as opposed to the one reported by `df` **(882G)**, thank's `fdisk` for giving me more space! But I would like to know which command is telling the truth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They’re all telling the truth, they’re just measuring different quantities.

`fdisk` shows your partition’s size: this measures raw sectors on your drive.

`df` shows usable space. Starting with the 897.1GiB of your partition, you lose some space to your file system’s data structures, resulting in `df`’s reported 882GiB total. Then you “lose” the reserved space, which you accounted for.

Comment: That's the 882GiB is the total size of the data blocks within the filesystem? And this  882GiB does not account for the filesystem's structure (superblocks, inode tables, ...).

Comment: That’s right. You can store up to 882GiB of files in your file system; the file system’s data structures make up the difference to 897.1GiB.